# global variable does not upgrade (c language)

Tags: c, global-variables

in my code I have a global variable **unsigned char String[10]** and the function:

```
//-----------------------UART_ConvertUDec-----------------------
// Converts a 32-bit number in unsigned decimal format
// Input: 32-bit number to be transferred
// Output: store the conversion in global variable String[10]
// Fixed format 4 digits, one space after, null termination
// Examples
//    4 to "   4 "  
//   31 to "  31 " 
//  102 to " 102 " 
// 2210 to "2210 "
//10000 to "**** "  any value larger than 9999 converted to "**** "
void UART_ConvertUDec(unsigned long n){
// as part of Lab 11 implement this function
    int i = 3;
    if (n > 9999){
        char String[] = "**** ";
    }
    else{
        char String[] = "     ";
    do{
            String[i] = 0x30+(n%10);
            n /= 10;
            i--;
        } while(n != 0);
    }
}
```

do you know why after the end of the function the value of **String[]** does not update?

Comment: Q: What compiler/what platform?  Q: Are you aware that the lines `{ char String[] = ... }` are WRONG?  They both have [block scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/), which is probably NOT what you want!  Instead, use `strcpy(String, "     ");` to update your global variable.

Comment: you are absolutely right, thank you so much for clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

you created 2 variables with the same name.

```
unsigned char String[10]
```

You do not provide it in code snippet where it's defined.

and

```
char String[]
```

in function,  most propably  your do... while... is modyfying
`char String[]`instead of `unsigned char String[10]`

But I'm wondering why compiler lets you run the code where 2 variables have the same name.

```
    void UART_ConvertUDec(unsigned long n, unsigned char* String, unsigned char lenght){
// as part of Lab 11 implement this function
    int i = 3;
    do{
            String[i] = 0x30+(n%10);
            n /= 10;
            i--;
            lenght--;
        } while(n != 0 && lenght >0);
    }
}
```